# replace all captured groups

Tags: java, regex, capturing-group

I need to transform something like: `"foo_bar_baz_2"` to `"fooBarBaz2"`

I'm trying to use this Pattern:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("_([a-z])");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("foo_bar_baz_2");
```

Is it possible to use `matcher` to replace the first captured group (the letter after the '_') with the captured group in upper case?

Comment: Yes, it is possible (I guess someone who knows Java better than me can also tell you how). I just wanted to point out that using that regex, you'll get `fooBarBaz_2` because `[a-z]` doesn't match `2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use appendReplacement/appendTail methods of the matcher like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("_([a-z0-9])");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("foo_bar_baz_2");

StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
while(matcher.find()) {
    matcher.appendReplacement(stringBuffer, matcher.group(1).toUpperCase());
}
matcher.appendTail(stringBuffer);

System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Replace with `\U$1\E` - represented as in Java string `"\\U$1\\E"`

As long as there is nothing else in your regex, you can dump the `\E` and shorten to `\U$1`.

---

Taking @TimPietzcker's comment into account, your regex itself should be `"_([a-z0-9])"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (matcher.find()) {
    matcher.appendReplacement(sb, matcher.group(1).toUpperCase());
}
matcher.appendTail(sb);
```