# Camel case Validation for String in android

Tags: java, android

I have a `String test="The Mountain view"`, i need all character after a space in a String need to be in Upper case , for example in the above text `'M'` is uppercase after space, the condition need to be reflect for every character after space in String.

I need a regular expression or condition to check all character after space is in Upper case or else i need change  the String after space into upper case character if it is in lower case.

If anyone knows means help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761658/replace-all-captured-groups) post, there it is asked to replace all characters to an uppercase after a `_`.  You can use the same solution.

Comment: You can do by splitting the String into Array then check the first letter, there may be some other better options also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need for regular expressions. Try this example, maybe helps:

```
public class Capitalize {

    public static String capitalize(String s) {
        if (s.length() == 0) return s;
        return s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
            String line = StdIn.readLine();
            String[] words = line.split("\\s");
            for (String s : words) {
                StdOut.print(capitalize(s) + " ");
            }
            StdOut.println();
        }
    }

}
```